# Are the "natural transformations" we apply on Coyoneda to get a Functor actually "natural transformations"?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

I have a theoretical question about the nature of a type that is used in
a lot of examples explaining the Coyoneda lemma. They are usually referred to
as "natural transformations" which to my knowledge mappings between functors.
What puzzles me is that in these examples they sometimes map from `Set` to some functor `F`. So it does not really semm to be a mapping between functors but something a little more relaxed.

Here is the code in question:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Coyo where

import           Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

data Coyoneda f a where
  Coyoneda :: (b -> a) -> f b -> Coyoneda f a

instance Functor (Coyoneda f) where
  fmap f (Coyoneda c fa) =  Coyoneda (f . c) fa

set :: Set Int
set = Set.fromList [1,2,3,4]

lift :: f a -> Coyoneda f a
lift fa = Coyoneda id fa

lower :: Functor f => Coyoneda f a -> f a
lower (Coyoneda f fa) = fmap f fa

type NatT f g = forall a. f a -> g a

coyoset :: Coyoneda Set Int
coyoset = fmap (+1) (lift set)

applyNatT :: NatT f g -> Coyoneda f a -> Coyoneda g a
applyNatT n (Coyoneda f fa) = Coyoneda f (n fa)

-- Set.toList is used as a "natural transformation" here
-- while it conforms to the type signature of NatT, it
-- is not a mapping between functors `f` and `g` since
-- `Set` is not a functor.
run :: [Int]
run = lower (applyNatT Set.toList coyoset)
```

What am I misunderstanding here?

**EDIT:** After a discussion on #haskell in freenode I think I need to clarify my question a little. It's basically: "What is `Set.toList` in a
category theoretic sense? Since it is obviously(?) not a natural transformation".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For `n` to be a natural transfomation in Haskell it needs to obey (for all `f`)

```
(fmap f) . n == n . (fmap f)
```

This isn't the case for `Set.toList`.

```
fmap (const 0) . Set.toList        $ Set.fromList [1, 2, 3] = [0, 0, 0]
Set.toList     . Set.map (const 0) $ Set.fromList [1, 2, 3] = [0]
```

Instead it obeys a different set of laws. There is another transformation `n'` back the other way such that the following holds

```
n' . (fmap f) . n == fmap f
```

If we choose `f = id` and apply the functor law `fmap id == id` we can see that this implies that `n' . n == id` and therefore we have a similar formula:

```
(fmap f) . n' . n == n' . (fmap f) . n == n' . n . (fmap f)
```

`n = Set.toList` and `n' = Set.fromList` obey this law.

```
Set.map (const 0) . Set.fromList   . Set.toList        $ Set.fromList [1, 2, 3] = fromList [0]
Set.fromList      . fmap (const 0) . Set.toList        $ Set.fromList [1, 2, 3] = fromList [0]
Set.fromList      . Set.toList     . Set.map (const 0) $ Set.fromList [1, 2, 3] = fromList [0]
```

I don't know what we can call this other than observing that `Set` is an equivalence class of lists. `Set.toList` finds a representative member of the equivalence class and `Set.fromList` is the quotient.

It's probably worth noting that `Set.fromList` is a natural transformation. At least it is on the reasonable subcategory of **Hask** where `a == b` implies `f a == f b` (here [`==`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-61--61-) is equality from `Eq`) . This is also the subcategory of **Hask** where `Set` is a functor; it excludes [degenerate things like this](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/chad/snippets/random-code-snippets/set-is-not-a-functor).

[leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout) also pointed out that `Set.toList` is a natural transformation on the subcategory of **Hask** where morphisms are restricted to [injective functions where `f a == f b` implies `a == b`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

Comment: On the injective subcategory, even `toList` is a natural transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
So `n'` and `n` form a section/retraction pair here?

Comment: @raichoo Yes, `n` and `n'` are a whole family of section/retraction pairs, since `n' . n == id`. Not all section/retraction pairs will obey the stronger law `n' . fmap f . n == fmap f`.